# Can't install Windows 8.1 Update - Error 0x800f081f

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

My laptop came with Windows 8 pre-installed. I installed all Microsoft updates, including that to 8.1 and have continued to do so.

The latest update which has come through is KB 2912355 which is a massive 890 MB. This has refused ti install, despite many attempts.

The system reports error `800F081F`. Having looked at Microsoft online support, I have tried the following :-

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

this failed with the following comments :-

```
The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not found or the component store cannot be repaired.
Error: 0x800f081f
```

I have therefor tried the next suggestion under 'repair a Windows image'  :-

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
```

This reported :-

```
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

I next ran :-

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
```

This also reported :-

```
The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

I therefore next ran :-

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

The output was :-

```
The restore operation failed. Either the repair source was not fou
onent store cannot be repaired.

Error: 0x800f081f

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Error: 87
The cleanup-image option is unknown.
For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.
```

I did have a look at the DISM help, but the options are so many and so complicated that I didn't get anywhere.

According to Microsoft, I have an image which is repairable, but nothing they have suggested worked!

I'd be very grateful if anyone could suggest what to try next!

Comment: Open a command prompt as administrator, and run this command: `sfc /scannow`. Post the command output when done. Then upload somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about) the `CBS.log` file (usually located in `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS`) and post here the resulting link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch a Command Prompt with administrator privileges
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14
   ```
3. Once step 2 is completed, run this command:

   ```
   dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
   ```
4. Try to install the Windows 8.1 update manually

Answer (score 0):

How about downloading the Windows 8.1 ISO?

From this article:

### http://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/

Once the ISO is on your computer (the Downloads folder is a good place for it)
mount the ISO and find and run Setup. The ensuing process will be automatic and should work well. Takes a while, of course.

This should override any problems, and give you the Update to 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

The download may be corrupt. Try stopping the Windows Update service and deleting the files in:

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
```

Open Windows Update and check for updates again.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple threads about corruption or corrupted files that prevent the Windows auto update files from downloading and completing the installation. I tried it all: DISM commands, SFC, the Troubleshooting tool (Update reset), etc.

The only thing that worked was [to use Windows installer to repair the installation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media). I was ready to do a reinstall of Windows 8/8.1. The previous link lets you create an installation media with USB drive or a DVD, and do a totally non-destructive repair of your Windows 8.1 installation. It keeps all your files and installed applications. You must choose the right version for your PC.

You can follow [a helpful guide](https://www.winhelp.us/non-destructive-reinstall-of-windows-8-and-8-1.html) to let you proceed. It includes temporary key-codes for Windows to allow it to proceed. (These will let you install Windows, but will not activate it (you can use your existing key-code that you can use a tool to find).

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  You just confirm you had the issue also then reference a third-party website which has hostile advertisements.